# PDO MySQL on Class functions

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

I have a class called Form. and I have a add_form() method which I call to save record to the database. add_form() basically adds the record to the database and returns rows affected. When I am using this function without the use of Classes or OOP Approach, it works fine. But now I get error says exec() is an undefined function. and variable count not defined? I use exec() because it returns rows affected instead of execute() which only executes the query.

```
class Forms
{
  private $database;
  private $count;

  public function __construct(PDO $database) 
  {
    $this->database = $database;
  }

  function add_form($lastname, $firstname, $island, $region, $province, $baranggay, $city, $address, $gender, $birthdate)
  {
    $sql  = "INSERT INTO forms (lastname, firstname, island, region, province, baranggay, city, address, gender, birthdate) VALUES (:lastname, :firstname, :island, :region, :province, :baranggay, :city, :address, :gender, :birthdate)";
    $stmt = $this->database->prepare($sql);
    $count->exec(array(
                  ':lastname'=>$lastname,
                  ':firstname'=>$firstname,
                  ':island'=>$island,
                  ':region'=>$region,
                  ':province'=>$province,
                  ':baranggay'=>$baranggay,
                  ':city'=>$city,
                  ':address'=>$address,
                  ':gender'=>$gender,
                  ':birthdate'=>$birthdate
                  ));
    return $count;
   }

}
```

Comment: Please, in the future: include error messages in full + tell us what you've tried to debug your code yourself... And of course: [RT(F)M](http://www.php.net/PDO)...

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things, first: the method you need to call is called [`PDOStatement::execute`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php), not `exec`. The `exec` method is a method of the `PDO` class [as the manual clearly shows](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php). `PDO::exec`, however, isn't very safe, because it does not use prepared statements, so it's good of you to use a `PDOStatement`, but then use the appropriate methods. It's quite easy to get the number of affected rows from a prepared statement, too...
Next, you assign the prepared statement (`PDOStatement` instance) to a variable called `$stmt`, but are calling `exec` on an *undefined variable*: `$count`:

```
   $stmt = $this->database->prepare($sql);
   $count->exec(array( //<--- should be $stmt->execute(array());
                  ':lastname'=>$lastname,
                  ':firstname'=>$firstname,
                  ':island'=>$island,
                  ':region'=>$region,
                  ':province'=>$province,
                  ':baranggay'=>$baranggay,
                  ':city'=>$city,
                  ':address'=>$address,
                  ':gender'=>$gender,
                  ':birthdate'=>$birthdate
));
```

Then, to get the number of affected rows, you need to call [the `rowCount` method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php):

```
return $stmt->rowCount();
```

Put these issues together, and applied to your code, you should change your code to:

```
$stmt->execute(array());
$count = $stmt->rowCount();
//optional:
$stmt->closeCursor();
return $count;
```

For completeness, here's an unsafe version using `exec`:

```
$vals = array(
    'firstname' => 'Joe',
    'lastname'  => 'Goodboy'
);
$count = $pdo->exec(
    'INSERT INTO hackable (firstname, lastname)
    VALUES ("'.$vals['firstname'].'", "'.$vals['lastname'].'")'
);//all is well
//BUT:
$vals = array(
    'firstname' => 'Evil", /*', 
    'lastname'  => '*/ (SELECT CONCAT_WS(",", id, username, password)
        FROM users
        WHERE isAdmin = 1
        LIMIT 1
    )); --'
$count = $pdo->exec(
    'INSERT INTO hackable (firstname, lastname)
    VALUES ("'.$vals['firstname'].'", "'.$vals['lastname'].'")'
);//OUCH!!
```

The latter input results in the query:

```
INSERT INTO hackable (firstname, lastname)
VALUES ("Evil", /*, "*/
    (SELECT CONCAT_WS(",", id, username, password)
     FROM users
     WHERE isAdmin = 1
    )); -- ", "")
```

Which just goes to show that executing a query with user input is just a bad idea...

*As an asside, some code-review*:
Please, make it a habit to *always* write the access modifiers, and [subscribe to the coding standards most major players subscribe to](http://www.php-fig.org). That means methods should be camalCased: `add_form` should be `addForm`. Also do yourself a favour, and add doc-blocks:

```
/**
 * Inserts data provided by $bind into forms table
 * @param array $bind
 * @return int
 * @throw PDOException (if PDO::ERRMODE is set to PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)
 */
public function addForm(array $bind)
{//PUBLIC + camelCased name
    $stmt = $this->database->prepare($queryString);
    $stmt->execute($bind);
    return $stmt->rowCount();
}
```

But on the whole, this *form* has a fixed layout, and a given number of values is expected. In larger projects, you'll probably end up defining a data class for this:

```
class From extends DataModel
{//where DataModel is an abstract class
    protected $lastname = null;
    protected $firstname = null;
    //all properties hiere
    public function __construct(array $data)
    {//use assoc array in constructor
        foreach ($data as $key => $value)
        {
            $setter = 'set'.ucfirst($key);
            if (method_exists($this, $setter))//define setters for properties!
                $this->{$setter}($value);
        }
    }
    /**
     * method to turn instance into bind array
     * Optionally omit null values for WHERE clauses
     * @param bool $includeNulls = true
     * @return array
     */
    public function toBind ($includeNulls = true)
    {
        $bind = array(
            ':firstname' => $this->firstname,
            ':lastname'  => $this->lastname,
            //do this for all properties
        );
        if ($includeNulls === false)
            return array_filter($bind);//unset null values
        return $bind;
    }
}
```

If you want to know why I urge you to use setters and getters, instead of magic `__get` and `__set` calls, [check out some of my answers on codereview.stackexchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/29617/is-this-a-bad-way-of-setting-properties-inside-of-a-class-php/29643#29643). I've explained it all before in detail